# Problema al instalar modulos de python para odoo

Tags: python, odoo

He instalado odoo en local,segun la documentacion me pide hacer el siguiente comando en la carpeta de instalacion

pip install -r requirements.txt

Aparentemente empieza bien,pero cuando va modulo por modulo saltan errores y no se instalan,al final me deja este mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como arreglarlo?
aunque instale modulo por modulo,python no los pilla.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.